# replacing a comma in uitextfield content

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm facing a strange scenario in my swift code. I have multiple uitexfields that I have set their keyboard type to decimalPad. My users will be Arabic, so they will either input numbers in English or Arabic. I've no problem with English integers and decimals and Arabic integers. However, if they try to enter arabic decimal numbers, the app crashes. The decimalPad in the iphone shows "," as a decimal separator for Arabic numbers, so I tried to change it to "." because I had to convert Arabic numbers to English ones before doing any mathmatical operation.

In the xCode simulator, it changes "،" to "." and then i can add or subtract or whatever i want with the user's input. BUT i can't do that if i use "," it just 
crashes!!!

Here's part of my code where I change the Arabic numbers to English ones:

```
if income.text?.isEmpty ?? true {            
   //income.text = "this is empty"
   // incomeNumber += 0.0           
} else {           
   if let temp = income.text {         
      let replaced = String(temp.characters.map {
          $0 == "،" ? "." : $0
      })                
      let incomeStr: String = replaced         
      let incomeFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
      incomeFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
      let incomeFinal = incomeFormatter.number(from: incomeStr)
      benifit.append(Double(incomeFinal!))
   }
}
```

This code works in the simulator, but if I change "،" to "," it doesn't work even though the iphone numberPad has "," NOT "،"!!!

Comment: It' crashing probably because you are force unwrapping a value that is nil.

Comment: Where is it crashing?

Comment: In the simulator, I can enter "," as a decimal point. However, in the iPhone, it crashes and gives me this message in the console:  " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-02-01 14:42:58.932937 بزنسي[5085:1561032] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) " It's like the iphone ignores number with "," as decimal point. Could it be because "," in my labtop is different from "," found in iphone numberPad? @Andrea

Comment: The above is where the crash happens @russell

Comment: That's a description of **how** the crash happens - but which line of code crashes?  Are you debugging with breakpoints?  In case you're not - can I suggest you put a breakpoint on the line with `if let temp` and step through, checking what happens to your variables at each step.